# Page is not returning 404 while directing to custom 404 error page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have created a **custom 404 page named file-not-found.php** in my website. And I changed the **.htaccess** file to,

```
ErrorDocument 404 /file-not-found.php
```

This is working perfectly okay and I also fetched a non existing url with Google webmaster tools and it displays correct 404 error.

I am deleting my articles after a specific time period.So what I decided to do was to **redirect users for file-not-found.php with 404 status code** if they looking for a removed content.So in the article page I wrote the following code

```
<?php 
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)!=0){
//display content
}else{
//redirect to custom error page
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
header('location:file-not-found.php');
exit();
}
?>
```

So now if the user request a removed content it redirects to the custom 404 page.

But the problem is if I fetch for a removed content link from Google webmaster tools it's returning status 200 rather than 404.

So Where would be the problem please help me to correct this issue.Thanks all.

Comment: wouldn't the 200 (ok) be a 200 for the 404 page? ie google found the 404 page (as it was redirected)

Comment: @James Yes may be but how I got to know whether it is correct or not?

Comment: Are you issuing a `header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');` on file-not-found.php

Comment: @Orangepill Yes friend I have tried both without and with issuing header.But same thing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `file-not-found.php` file should contain `header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');`
2. remove `header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');` before `header('Location:file-not-found.php');` as a redirect code should be `301` if moved permanently or `302` for normal redirect. [source](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: Thanks friend.Will it cause infinite loop on file-not-found.php since I redirect 404 errors for file-not-found.php in `.htaccess` also

Comment: If `file-not-found.php` doesn't redirect, it will not redirect to itself. When you are writing this `ErrorDocument 404 /file-not-found.php`, you only rewrite Apache's error page.